# Combine imap_open and stdin

Tags: php, imap, stdin

Can imap_open and php://stdin be combined to open a imap email stream?
I have the below code but nothing's happening. Please help. My email is an internet email and am running this php script from a localhost.

```
<?php
//imap server logon details

    $server = "{mail.domain.com:993/ssl}";
    $username = "myname@domain.com";
    $password = "mypassword";

    // connect to the imap sever
    $con_mailbox = imap_open($server, $username, $password);

    $email = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
    preg_match_all("/(.*):\n(.*)\n/i", $email, $matches);

    mail(myname@domain.com, 'Successfully Connected to server', 'From:noreply@domain.com');

?>
```

Comment: What do you want to do from stdin?  Send an email?  Parse an email?  You don't need IMAP to do either of those.

Comment: Max, thanks for the reply. The objective of my project is I want to parse the email contents. I am on a windows system and i want to use imap_open to connect to my external web email and try to open and read the contents with php;//stdin and parse the email headers and the body with php.

Comment: If you're connecting to an IMAP server, you don't need to use php://stdin.  You would fetch the contents of the email into a variable, and parse the variable directly.  I don't understand why you're trying to redirect it via stdin.

Comment: Thanks Max, you are right. My bad. I got it. I don't need stdin. Refer my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Max for replying to my post. I found the answer myself. I managed to parse the imap email and extracted the variables i needed and inserted them into a database. I was working on a Helpdesk project. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please include some details on **how** you solved your problem? As it stands, this answer is no help to other users, as it gives no detail on what the solution was.